# What does the magicFutureSetting application manifest property do?

Tags: winapi, manifest

The documentation for [application manifests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191.aspx) specifies an option named [magicFutureSetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191.aspx#magicFutureSetting), yet doesn't describe what it does.

What does this property do?

Comment: Magic, but not directly. Later. More seriously, nobody seems to know according to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it looks to me like a way to test that some setting in the future can be included then accessed via an API like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375700(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That function has a parameter `settingsNameSpace`, which is used to pass in the URL for the manifest schema to be used. This would indicate to query newer options you pass in a newer schema, wouldn't it?